# MS Access From Wide Format to Long Format New variable Union ALL

Tags: sql, append, union

I'm a newbie at MS Access and need some help. I have a table that looks like this:

| ID | HDD | CDD | HDDKEY | CDDKEY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 186 | -1 | -1 | 1 | 5 |

and would like the following:

| ID | HDD | CDD | KEY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 186 | -1 | 0 | 1 |
| 186 | 0 | -1 | 5 |

My code -that does not work:

````
SELECT 
TABL1.ID, 
TABL1.HDD, 
TABL1.CDD, 
'KEY'  = HDDKEY
FROM TABL1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
TABL1.ID, 
TABL1.HDD, 
TABL1.CDD, 
'KEY'  = CDDKEY
FROM TABL1

WHERE (((TABL.ID)=18676));```

Thank you!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close

```
SELECT TABL1.ID, TABL1.HDD, 0 AS CDD, HDDKEY as [Key]
FROM TABL1
WHERE ID = 186
UNION ALL
SELECT TABL1.ID, 0 AS HDD, TABL1.CDD, CDDKEY as [Key]
FROM TABL1
WHERE ID = 186;
```

Note that `KEY` is a poor name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.